# AttributeError: module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'LGBMClassifier'

Tags: lightgbm

I installed lightgbm with `conda install -c creditx lightgbm=0.2.0`,and import lightgbm success, but when I import `LGBMClassifier` or using `LGBMClassifier` it fails.

Error is:

```
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Final_Contest/ligGBM.py", line 12, in <module>
    gbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary',num_leaves=31,learning_rate=0.1,n_estimators=3000)
AttributeError: module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'LGBMClassifier'
```

What could be the case?

Comment: update sklearn to 0.18.2 may help!

Comment: you may need to check whether you have a local file named lightgbm.py

Answer (score 0):

I removed the graphviz and lightgbm package from Anaconda Prompt and installed the libraries using conda install.
It worked for me.